# STS installation Java version issue

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

I am trying to install Spring in my windows PC....I have installed JDK7 32 bit as STS doesn't support 64 bit in windows. 
Previous SO questions gave suggestions to add -vm path in STS.ini file.
But I am still getting this issue. Any idea is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: This usually leaves an error log with details. Please please post the log contents

Comment: Please see my error log here...http://pastebin.com/P2sbjLvf @SasikanthBharadwaj

Answer (score 0):

STS latest version now supports 64 bit JDK7.
I saw the STS error log [pastebin.com/P2sbjLvf](http://pastebin.com/P2sbjLvf) , it said 'Cannot load 64-bit SWT libraries on 32-bit JVM.'

Using 64bit JDK7 and changing appropriate -vm path in STS.ini fixed everything.

Cheers.